# How to do the barcode reader in the php?

Tags: php, jquery, barcode, barcode-scanner

How to read the barcode by using the php

**Steps done**

I have generate the barcode by using the tcpdf scripts.

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/tcpdf_barcodes_1d_include.php');

// set the barcode content and type
$barcodeobj = new TCPDFBarcode('http://www.tcpdf.org', 'C128');

// output the barcode as SVG image
$barcodeobj->getBarcodeSVG(2, 30, 'black');
```

[image][http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/barcodes/example_1d_svg.svg]

But i don't know how to read the normal Barcode Image by using php.

And also i don't exactly what the barcode reader produces after scanning the barcode.But While surfing the sites i have seen that it will produce an output of 1-2-3-4 while scanning the barcode denoting the 1234. **Please correct me if the output of the barcode reader differs from what i told**

Comment: what did you tried till now. Please edit your question showing more information (code/data).

Comment: i have added how i created the barcode... by using tcpdf  @jogo

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this. Don't you use a barcode scanner to scan the image and it handles the job of decoding? Only thing you have to do is save the code somewhere

When the code is scanned and given to the server, it will search for that code and thats how it goes.

This is the reason almost all libraries like this don't include a read/decode functionality.